# Calling service methods from javascript getting error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

we developed restful service using asp.net MVC4 web API,calling that service from PostMan is working fine,but will calling methods from Html page using JavaScript it shows error, plz any one help me

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() 
            {
                $("#btnShow").click(function() 
                  {$.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                    url: "http://eprescription.smartelectronicprescriptions.com/api/login",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{}',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) 
                {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic", encodeunpwd());
                },
                 success: function (msg) 
                    {
                    alert("Success");
                        },
                 error: function (msg)
                     {
                     alert("error");
                     }
            });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a FQDN for the url, this is probably dropping in a jsonp request which is what is causing the error.

I can only assume this however as you haven't stated the error, have you tried looking at an example like this:

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

It might help you get started on fixing it

Comment: Thanks @slicksim for reply.. error was XMLHttpRequest cannot load "http:...". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. plz help me to solve this...

Comment: yes.. we already put <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

Comment: below link solved my problem http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-cross-domain-ajax-call-with-get-request/